# Why do Ubuntu and Debian still only ship usbutils 007 while it's 5 years old and new versions are available?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, distributions

As I understand, usbutils 008 [was released](https://lwn.net/Articles/617570/) 4 years ago, and current version is 010. The latest version is [being installed](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/usbutils.html) in BLFS, but in Ubuntu it's [still 007](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/usbutils) in latest development release (Cosmic), same [in Debian Sid](https://packages.debian.org/sid/usbutils)*.

I do realize that, as noted [in LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/617570/), usbutils 008 changes the way it looks for device descriptions to a systemd-reliant one (`hwdb` instead of `usb.ids`). But LFS doesn't enforce any policy regarding systemd, but still provides latest version of usbutils. OTOH, Debian and Ubuntu are already committed to systemd, so why are they lagging with their version?

---

<sub>* Admittedly, Debian Experimental does have usbutils 010, but that still makes me wonder why not Sid or even Stretch/Buster</sub>

Comment: To the close voters: the answer isn't opinion based: there must be a real reason why the maintainers chose to avoid upgrading. If it's based on an opinion, it's only on the maintainers' opinion. And I suppose that must be documented somewhere, and I just don't know where.

Comment: The A'ers that we can enlist here will be opinion based since only the person that did that commit or group can really say one way or another why. I try to think of ways to ask this Q so that it won't be opinions and I think the best way to get this A'er would be on an actual Debian/Ubuntu forum, outside of one of those "devs" happening across your Q on our site. You could also reach out to AU or even IRC.

Comment: @slm I kinda think that would make for an A to this Q. I think there could be multiple reasons, for example some complex dependency chain or any other technical reason behind the choice of version here. I think answers would only be opinion-based if they're blind guesses, but if there's an actual technical reason behind this (and I don't see why the reason shouldn't be technical) there can be a good answer to this question, supported by documentation/commits/etc.